# vue config js works fine locally but not working in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

works fine when I make API calls on the local server, but I keep getting a 404 error on the Heroku deployed app.

**config.js file**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://simple-order-api.herokuapp.com',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**store/index.js File**

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    baseUrl: '/api',
  },
});
```

***auth.js File***

```
  actions: {
    register({ commit, state }) {
      commit('setRegisterError', null);
      return HTTP().post('/auth/register', {
        email: state.registerEmail,
        password: state.registerPassword,
      })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          commit('setToken', data.token);
          router.push('/');
        })
        .catch(() => {
          commit('setRegisterError', 'An error occured while creating your account');
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: hi Tuza, this needs more details for us to be helpful. can you explain what the expected API response is vs what you are receiving? also, is the front end deployed, or just the API?

Comment: The expected response is 200, i am getting a 404. this means i am not actually hitting the endpoint.

The front end is deployed on Heroku ( https://simple-order-app.herokuapp.com ) 

back end as well ( https://simple-order-api.herokuapp.com ). 

Hitting the endpoint works fine on my localhost. but returns 404 error on the Heroku deployed ( https://simple-order-app.herokuapp.com )

Comment: `devServer.proxy` is only active in your development server (i.e., it doesn't rewrite URLs in your build output). You'll want to rewrite your URLs a different way. For example, you could create an Axios instance that has a baseURL set as needed, and use that instance to post your data.

Comment: Thanks. problem solved